# Applications late to load on startup

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

When my computer is starting up, after few applications load, and the computer is at idle status, I check that task manager and the resource monitor, and verify that there is no cpu or disk activity, about a minute later, I see few startup programs starting to load.

What is happening, and how can I replicate that on any other program that I want to put at startup ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you delay the launch of an application in Windows 7 at startup?](http://superuser.com/questions/167933/how-do-you-delay-the-launch-of-an-application-in-windows-7-at-startup) also check out [What does “delayed start” do in startup type for a Windows service?](http://superuser.com/questions/285653/what-does-delayed-start-do-in-startup-type-for-a-windows-service)

Comment: Are you connected to a domain ? network ? what the few startup programs are ?

Comment: @techie007 that is correct, I will flag this question as duplicate.