# How to disable Wi-Fi on start up?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, boot

I'm using Windows 7, and it always starts with Wi-Fi enabled, then it becomes very slow. I can see a blue circle turning on the Wi-Fi icon in the task bar.

Is there a way to disable Wi-Fi during Windows 7 start up?

Comment: Do you want to disable it permanently or delay it for a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 6):

You could go into the "Network and Sharing Center" and use the "Change adapter settings" option to disable the wireless adapter (right-click on the adapter and you should see "Disable" as the first option).

[image: Network and Sharing Center]

If you don't want to disable the wireless adapter you can set the wireless service to start automatically, but with a delay.

I don't have a laptop on hand, but if you type `services` in the start search and open the services control panel, you should find a service called "WLAN AutoConfig". Right-click on the service and choose Properties from the context menu. On the General step you can set the startup type to one of the following:

- Automatic (Delayed Start)
- Automatic
- Manual
- Disabled

If you choose the "Automatic (Delayed Start)" option, the service should start after all of the other Automatic services.

This link will provide more information regarding the Automatic (Delayed Start) "wait" time:
[How much time a delayed service waits to start?](https://superuser.com/questions/284698/how-much-time-a-delayed-service-waits-to-start)

Comment: On some computers, there's also a hardware switch you could use.

Comment: It's dangerous to go alone! Take [this](http://i.imgur.com/qbqj3vS.png).

Comment: I couldn't set WLAN AutoConfig as delayed start.Per http://forum.sysinternals.com/the-delayed-autostart-flag-could-not-be-set_topic30715.html
"Many services are members of service groups. Many of these groups have entries in the ServiceGroupList in the registry that controls the order in which the services are started. Many services must be started in a specific order. Services that are members of such a group cannot be set to Delayed start."